# Company restriction for some users in dynamics ax 2009

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to restrict a user to access only 2 or 3 companies. I have added code to filter companies in SysDataAreaSelect form but it works only for the link which is present in the status bar. It did not worked for the companies list showing in breadcrumb bar. I can hide breadcrumb bar but if I do that, the link present in status bar also hide.

Is there any way to override SysDataAreaSelect form with a new form or any solution of the above stated problem ?

Comment: It is possible to disable changing companies in the breadcrumb bar from the User groups permissions form.  Select the Tools option and then Select company accounts (AX 2009)...  User groups belong to Domains.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for are Domains in user security. Domains are simply groups of companies; when a user is assigned permissions within a domain, they can access the particular permission in all companies within that domain. If a user does not have any permissions within a company, they will not see the company in the dropdown list.

You can read more on domains here:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834373(v=ax.50).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834373%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)

Comment: We cannot use that approach because of some reasons. Can you suggest any other appoach ?

Comment: There aren't any others that I'm aware of. I did find something elsewhere that seems to be asking the same thing you are: [link](http://objectmix.com/axapta/791746-restrict-users-ability-change-company.html)
The primary conclusion to that discussion was that Domains were the only effective way to lock down a user to specific companies. A single user group can have different permissions in multiple domains (for example, edit to domain A, view to the same element in domain B), which would flow to the companies within those domains, if that is the primary concern with this approach.